# What phrase is used to describe the subsequent act in a series of performances

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, the MC at a talent show might say:

"Currently on stage is [Performance 1], up next we have [Performance 2] and [Performance 3] is ____."

I know the phrase exists because I've heard it recently at a competition but I can't remember what the presenters said (the usage of this phrase was consistent throughout the entire performance).

Also, I am 99% sure the phrase *wasn't*

> on deck

or

> in the bullpen

What else could it have been?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking here. You give a phrase and then you ask what the phrase is? Which part of the example you give is not right?

Comment: In baseball lingo, the batting order is *at bat*, *on deck*, *in the hole* - so the third performance would be *in the hole*, not *on deck*.

Comment: Although it wouldn’t fit your sentence, individual performances in a variety show are called _numbers_.

Comment: @Juhasz Bingo! Answer the question so I can give you the credit

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought you were looking for something that wasn't baseball-related.

Comment: We can't read your mind to determine the word you're thinking of. Either you have to be explicit about what it is, or all we can do is throw out synonyms (like *after that*), which almost certainly won't be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In baseball terminology, the player currently batting is described as *at bat*.  The player next in line is described as *on deck*.  The next player after that is *in the hole*.

A lot of caseball terminology has seeped into general American English. Phrases like *strike out*, *screwball*, *rain check* have all come into common use from baseball.

Other common English phrases used in baseball, but not originating there include: *shut out*, *bullpen*, (possibly) *southpaw*, *on-deck* and *in the hole*.

These last two both seem to have originated in naval or maritime lingo. Some sources claim that these terms were used on aircraft carriers to describe pilots in line to take off (["In the Hole or on Hold?"](https://co.milesplit.com/articles/205107-in-the-hole-or-on-hold)). According to this argument, a pilot not yet on deck waits "in the hole." What is *the hole*? These sources tend not to make any guesses. According to this [glossary of U.S. Naval slang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_U.S._Navy_slang), the hole is the "main machinery space where an engineer works. 'What do you do onboard?' 'I work in The Hole.' Also 'The Pit.'"

I don't know much about aircraft carriers, but it seems unlikely that a pilot would be hanging out with the engineers before going on-deck.

Other sources, including this one published by the MLB ([Discover the mysterious origins of some of baseball's most well-known terms](https://www.mlb.com/cut4/more-wacky-stories-behind-baseball-terms-c218978328)), claim that the phrase was originally "in the **hold**." The *hold* of a ship is typically the area where cargo is stored - also an unlikely place for a pilot to be waiting - but according to *Merriam-Webster*, it can also mean "the interior of a ship below decks" (["Hold"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold)).  Seems reasonable, but I remain unconvinced.